# Error: ELF error from deploying an anchor project

Tags: anchor, solana-program, pda, anchor-lang, deploy

I have been trying to deploy my anchor project on the local net. I started by running `solana-test-validator` and then `anchor deploy` but I keep receiving this error:

```
Error: ELF error: ELF error: Multiple or no text sections, consider removing llc option: -function-sections
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

Here are the versions that I am using:

```
anchor-cli 0.28.0
solana-cli 1.16.17
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that your built program has either no `.text` sections, or multiple `.text` sections. This section contains all of the compiled code for your program, and the Solana runtime only knows how to handle a program with one `.text` section.

Most likely, your program failed to build somewhere or didn't build, so be sure to run `anchor build` and see that it properly built.

If this doesn't resolve the issue, you'll need to provide more information, including your program's code and dependencies.